# Как добавить поиск в API Яндекс карт версии 3?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

В версии 2.1 поиск можно было добавлять как описано в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding/searchControl.html).

Не могу найти, как это сделать в [версии 3](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/).

---

В [мануале по переходу](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/upgrade/#controls) указано следующее:

> В API 3.0 остались только три элемента управления: геолокация, кнопки масштаба и обычная кнопка. [Подробнее](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/dg/concepts/controls/standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В новой версии API поиск пока реализован только в виде функции **[search](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/#search)**. Визуальные элементы управления вроде поисковой строки сейчас следует создавать самостоятельно.

Пример реализации поиска:

```
<input type="text" id="search">

var textInput = document.getElementById("search");
textInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
    // Поиск адреса по Enter
        ymaps3.search({
            'text': textInput.value
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res[0])
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: А на каком объекте её вызывать? На экземпляре самой карты?: Справочник ужасный — ничего непонятно)

Comment: Добавил пример кода. Рабочий вариант для проверки: https://jsbin.com/giqaqayodo/edit?js,console,output